# Joomla 3 Installation

Tags: php, joomla, installation, wamp

I have installed Wamp 2 and copied all the Joomla 3 folder files into the 'www' folder in wamp.  when I try to install Joomla  I get a message that I need a php version of atleast  5.3.1 or more but my wamp shows my phpversion is 5.3. Am confused, i need your help

Comment: Please show the full error message! Also is your phpversion 5.3.0 or 5.3.1? Also if you have a look at the Requirements you have to have at least version 5.3.10! See: http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

The minimum PHP version required for Joomla 3.x is now 5.3.10. This is because of the Bcrypt password encryption method used for an improvement in security.

My suggestion would be to simply scrap the wampserver version you're currently using and download the latest version (2.5) which includes PHP 5.5.12 and MySQ; 5.6.17.

This will ensure you're Joomla installation will run smoothly.

Always ensure you're running the latest version of anything you use in the web development world